# Solve for $s$: $s - \frac{s}{ 2^{\frac{f}{12}}} = w$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a (probably) relatively simple algebra question. The values $w$ & $f$ are unknown constants.

> Solve for $s$:
>
> $$s - \frac{s}{ 2^{\frac{f}{12}}} = w$$

Comment: HINT: Rewrite this equation as
$$s \left( 1- \frac{1}{2^{f/12}}\right) = w$$ so that the answer is $s=w\left( 1- \frac{1}{2^{f/12}}\right)^{-1} $

Comment: Hint: rewrite the first: $s$ as $1s$.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out $\;s\;$ :

$$s\left(1-\frac1{2^{f/12}}\right)=w\implies s=\frac{2^{f/12}}{2^{f/12}-1}\,w$$